# Google API - Google Play Services - Error 500 Message:Null

Tags: google-play-games, google-apis-explorer

Request URL:

https://content.googleapis.com/games/v1/players/[CORRECT_PLAYER_ID]?access_token=[CORRECT_APPLICATION_ACCESS_TOKEN]

The application is Server and set up like here:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

The only response is:

{
 "error": {
  "code": 500,
  "message": null
 }
}

In API Explorer I have:

...
  "code": 401,
  "message": "User has not completed registration."
...

What is wrong with my use case? How I can workaround Verification of Google Play Services User ID?

Answer (score 0):

A 500 response is a server-side error, which sounds more like a bug than a question. It looks like they have a place to report bugs [here](https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/support).

I think this might not execute through the APIs Explorer this way because you haven't registered your project with the credentials being used; it doesn't currently have a way to use your own credentials instead.